# subplot in matplotlib.pyplot from function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to create subplot by using some defined function, which returns directly plot. But I can't figure out why this is not working. for example:

my plot function is something like:

```
def plot_data(data):
    plt.plot(data)
    return plt.show()
```

suppose my data are:

```
data1 = np.random.rand(50)
data2 = np.random.rand(50)
data3 = np.random.rand(50)
data4 = np.random.rand(50)
```

and I am trying to create subplot with:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plot_data(data)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plot_data(data)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plot_data(data)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plot_data(data)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

it returns :
[image]

Comment: It might be worth noting that it is not necessary to have calls to `plt.subplot()` _and_ `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)`

Comment: Indeed that `plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)` is unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `return plt.show()` in your `plot_data()` function. That'll work.

In that case, it might be useless to even use that extra function `plot_data()` and you can directly use `plt.plot(data)` :-)

Comment: haha it works for me...Actually, in my real function, I have many calculations so I have defined function to plot..anyways thanks a lot :)

Comment: Heheh yes sure, if you have additional stuffs to do functions is a good habit.